# Is this object turn alone with torque inside disk of water?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, fluid-statics

This is not the original question, I changed for explain details. But now it's not possible to delete the question and now the reply is not in relation with question. I post a new question, and try to modify text with original question. Sorry.

[image: h]

[image: hn]

An object is composed by two disks, one bigger, one smaller. There is gas in each disk. I put this object in a big disk full of water, big enough for have gravity effect. I suppose this big disk fixed. No other gravity like Earth for example (theoretical problem).

Like gas object is asymmetrical it must have a torque if pressure is the same for a depth but pressure inside big disk change due to the lack of matter. So no torque. But if I add an external object of the same shape of the gas object but solid with the same density like water, it's possible to compensate near the pressure inside big disk for have a torque on gas object, it want to turn counter-clockwise. The external object want to turn counter-clockwise too ? Is it a torque on external object ?

[image: asy]

Comment: The way you fixed the small disc to the pink circle prevents it from turning on its own center...

Comment: I changed the problem for better details

Answer (score 2):

The only torque the small disc can experience is around the yellow point due to the way you have constrained it using the pink line. no such motion within this limit allows the air to move further away from the yellow point.

Comment: I changed a little the problem. Maybe you can explain if there is a torque on external object and in what direction ? thanks